# Does Collections.unmodifiableCollection(list) copy the collection?

Tags: java, collections

```
private List list;
```

If we use `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(list)`, will this return a copy of the collection, or is it faster than creating a copy? We could do `other.addAll(list)` but we have list of 600,000 object, so `addAll` is not so good.

Caller just needs a read-only collection.

Comment: This answer question clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`Collections.unmodifiableList` just returns an unmodifiable wrapper; it does not copy the contents of the input list.

Its [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) states this fairly clearly:

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.  This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.  Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

As Matt Ball mentioned, if you don't need the internal `List` to be mutable, you may want to just store a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) internally... you can safely give that to callers directly since it can never change.

Comment: Hmmm - you say javadoc states this fairly clearly but doesnt look clear to me. You mean because they say view? This is important thing so doc not clear IMO. I thnk should say uses wrapper and not copy collection like first answer said.

Comment: @Gorca: Yes, "view" does imply "not a copy". It would most likely say that it creates a copy if it did that. It also explains that it forwards query methods to the list it's given.

Answer (score 8):

> Does `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(list)` copy the collection?

The other answers are correct (`+1`s all around): the answer is **no.**

---

Instead of `Collections.unmodifiableList()` you can use [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`ImmutableList.copyOf()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf%28java.util.Collection%29) to create an immutable (not modifiable) list copy.

Comment: What is the advantage of the Guava method?

Comment: Brendan: read the last sentence of the answer closely. If you still don't see it, just read the JavaDoc.

Comment: I just don't see what the difference between "immutable" and "unmodifiable" is? I could read the Javadoc, but your answer would be more helpful if it explained what the difference is.

Comment: It creates a list **copy.** _"Despite the method name, this method attempts to avoid actually copying the data when it is safe to do so. The exact circumstances under which a copy will or will not be performed are undocumented and subject to change."_

Comment: @Brendan: The difference between immutable and unmodifiable is that immutable guarantees "this will never change" while unmodifiable just says "you cannot change this, but something else might be able to". The Guava method is preferable if you don't need to modify the list contents after first creating it... you can share it freely.

Comment: @BrendanLong Another big advantage of the Guava method is that, upon trying to modify an immutable (cannot change) field, you will (I'm betting) get a compile-time, rather than run-time, exception. Finding an error at compile-time rather than run-time is a significant benefit.

Answer (score 7):

`Collections.unmodifiableCollection(..)` simply wraps the original collection, disabling methods for modification. It doesn't copy it.

If you change the original list, the "unmodifiable" collection will also change. But the client having only the unmodifiable collection can't change it.